# Using iText 2.1.7 to merge large PDFs

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using an older version of iText (2.1.7) to merge PDFs. Because that is the last version under the MPL available to me. I cannot change this.

Anyways. I am trying to merge multiple PDFs. Everything seems to work ok, but when I go over about 1500 pages, then the generated PDF fails to open (behaves as if it is corrupted)

This is how I am doing it:

```
private byte[] mergePDFs(List<byte[]> pdfBytesList) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, outputStream);
    document.open();

    for (byte[] pdfByteArray : pdfBytesList) {
        ByteArrayInputStream readerStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfByteArray);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(readerStream);

        for (int i = 0; i < reader.getNumberOfPages(); ) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++i));
        }

        copy.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();
    }

    document.close();

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Is this the correct approach? Is there anything about this that would hint at breaking when going over a certain amount of pages? There are no exceptions thrown or anything.

Comment: Right approach, wrong version. In 2009, there was a limit on the size of the PDF in iText. Please upgrade. This question should be closed as off-topic: it's a problem that can no longer be reproduced. (People shouldn't use versions of iText that are 9 years old.)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie fair point. I wish I could use a later version. thanks for the input.

Comment: If I remember correctly there was a file size limit (2GB) but not a number of page limit. What is the size of your PDF? You may also try https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF which is based on 2.1.7 but still developed (I am not affiliated with that project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone curious, the issue had nothing to do with iText and instead was the code responsible for returning the response from iText.